# How to Implement `Year + 1` in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df`

```
      Date Filing Date Name
0  2013 Q2   8/17/2013  AAA
1  2013 Q3  11/19/2013  BBB
2  2013 Q4    2/2/2014  CCC
3  2014 Q4   2/13/2015  DDD
4  2015 Q1   5/12/2015  EEE
5  2015 Q2    8/7/2015  FFF
6  2015 Q3  11/20/2015  GGG
7  2016 Q4   2/19/2017  HHH
8  2019 Q4    2/4/2020  III
```

where I am updating the `Filing Date` column based on a mapping:

```
# Split Date Column into one column for Year, and one for Quarter
df['Year'], df['Quarter'] = df['Date'].str.split(' ', 1).str
# Replace Quarter values with date values
df['Filing Date'] = (df['Quarter'].map({'Q1': '5/15/', 'Q2': '8/15/','Q3': '11/15/', 'Q4': '2/15/'}) + df['Year'])
```

The problem is that for all `Q4` entries, the `Year` of the `Filing Date` should actually be the `Date` `Year + 1`. For example:

```
      Date Filing Date Name
2  2013 Q4   2/15/2014  CCC
3  2014 Q4   2/15/2015  DDD
7  2016 Q4   2/15/2017  HHH
8  2019 Q4   2/15/2020  III
```

I know I can probably do this by converting to dateime, loop through each row of the dataframe, and add 1 to the year for each `Q4` row. But that seems clunky and I have heard it's best to avoid looping through a dataframe. So is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: The dates aren't already in the appropriate format/type? Also, please share a [mcve], where the DataFrame is clearly defined and easy to use.

Comment: Is there a way to print the data frame so that it can be easily used on StackOverflow? I ask because I'm reading them from CSV files

Comment: You can use `DataFrame.to_dict()` or `.to_csv()`, for example. Of course this may get complicated depending on the data types. Since you're reading directly from a CSV, you could share part of the file, and the code to read it and set up the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to achieve your goal :

```
dic = {'Q1': '5/15/', 'Q2': '8/15/','Q3': '11/15/', 'Q4': '2/15/'}

df['Filing Date'] = np.where(df.Quarter=='Q4', 
                          df['Quarter'].map(dic)+df.Year.add(1).astype(str), 
                          df['Quarter'].map(dic)+df.Year.astype(str))

    Year    Quarter Filing Date Name
0   2013    Q2  8/15/2013   AAA
1   2013    Q3  11/15/2013  BBB
2   2013    Q4  2/15/2014   CCC
3   2014    Q4  2/15/2015   DDD
4   2015    Q1  5/15/2015   EEE
5   2015    Q2  8/15/2015   FFF
6   2015    Q3  11/15/2015  GGG
7   2016    Q4  2/15/2017   HHH
8   2019    Q4  2/15/2020   III
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the desired output. Column names and order need to match. I also get `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: Have a look at your dtypes to identify which column is generating the error. is your year column an int or a str? if it is a string, i would suggest you convert it to int, add 1, then revert to str. could u explain what you mean by column names and order need to match? are u referring to Filing_Date?

Comment: If I first convert `Year` to `datetime` then this looks to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary to increase the year by one if it is Q4: `int(yr) + (1 if qtr == 'Q4' else 0)`

```
import datetime as dt

# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2013 Q2', '2013 Q3', '2013 Q4', '2014 Q4', '2015 Q1', '2015 Q2', '2015 Q3', '2016 Q4', '2019 Q4'],
    'Filing Date': ['8/17/2013', '11/19/2013', '2/2/2014', '2/13/2015', '5/12/2015', '8/7/2015', '11/20/2015', '2/19/2017', '2/4/2020'],
    'Name': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'HHH', 'III']
})

# Solution.
quarter_to_month_mapping = {'Q1': 5, 'Q2': 8, 'Q3': 11, 'Q4': 2}
year, quarter = zip(*df['Date'].str.split(' ', 1))
df['Filing Date'] = pd.to_datetime([
    dt.date(
        year=int(yr) + (1 if qtr == 'Q4' else 0), 
        month=quarter_to_month_mapping[qtr], 
        day=15
    ) 
    for yr, qtr in zip(year, quarter)]
)
>>> df
      Date Filing Date Name
0  2013 Q2  2013-08-15  AAA
1  2013 Q3  2013-11-15  BBB
2  2013 Q4  2014-02-15  CCC
3  2014 Q4  2015-02-15  DDD
4  2015 Q1  2015-05-15  EEE
5  2015 Q2  2015-08-15  FFF
6  2015 Q3  2015-11-15  GGG
7  2016 Q4  2017-02-15  HHH
8  2019 Q4  2020-02-15  III
```